# Images from the internet don't show up in programs other than Web Clients (Web Browsers)

Tags: windows, browser, images

I'm running Windows 7 Ultimate 64 bit  and all web pages display fine in IE9/Chrome/FireFox but when I open a program which loads images from the internet; such as Napster/Windows Live Mail/Skype they don't show up; there's just nothing there where the images should be.

Anyone have any ideas what on earth is going on?

(Sorry if this isn't the right place to ask this question)

My default browser is Chrome

Comment: "Nothing" where the images should be?  No "little red X's", or placeholders?

Comment: They're just blank; they don't appear at all. If there's a solid background of colour; e.g. bgcolor in the html of html newsletter then that will show. I'm a website developer myself and I'm pretty certain the images aren't showing as opposed to not existing.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was a problem with IE or IE9. I degraded from IE9 to IE8 and now the problem no longer exists. Could be that it was slightly corrupt; not sure; but can't be bothered to upgrade again to find out :P

Thanks for your help